# Will the bindings defined in `letfn` be renewed every time `sqrt` is called?

Tags: clojure

Provided that `abs` and `avg` are defined:

```
(defn sqrt [x]
  (letfn [(s [guess]
            (if (good-enough? guess)
              guess
              (s (improve guess))))
          (good-enough? [guess]
            (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.0001))
          (improve [guess]
            (avg (/ x guess) guess))]
    (s 1.0)))
```

Please ignore for a sec that I'm reinventing the wheel here. :) This only serves as an example.

If so, is there a way to get around this so the names won't be bound again and again every time the function is called, and without introducing more names outside the function?

Comment: What do you mean by "redefined"?

Answer (score 3):

> Will the functions defined in `letfn` be redefined every time `sqrt` is called?

Yes.

The *bindings*  of `s` and `good-enough` will be remade every time the `sqrt` function is entered. The things they are bound to are constructed afresh.

- The `s` and `good-enough` functions (effectively `fn` special forms)
  are *compiled once*, when the `(defn sqrt ... )` is
  performed.
- They are closed over `x` for every call of `sqrt`.
- The closures might be implemented on the JVM as inner classes
  complying with the `IFn` interface.
- The closures/function-objects are constructed every time `sqrt` is
  entered, though the classes that they exemplify have been long compiled.

---

It depends what you mean by *redefined*. I thought *not*, but the elements on both sides of the bindings are renewed. So now I think *so*.

---

> is there a more idiomatic way to write the square root function?

Yes.

On the JVM ...

```
(defn sqrt [x] (Math/sqrt x))

(sqrt 2);1.4142135623730951
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "yes", the *bindings* will be renewed. However, this is as cheap as instantiating a very simple class. You can see below the decompiled java classes how the clojure is implemented with a simple parameter and how nested functions will result in just some more classes. So this is still very cheap.

```
public final class user$sqrt extends AFunction {
    public static final Object const__0 = Double.valueOf(1.0D);

    public static Object invokeStatic(Object x) {
        user$sqrt$s__44945 s = null;
        user$sqrt$good_enough_QMARK___44947 good_enough_QMARK_ = null;
        user$sqrt$improve__44949 improve = null;
        s = new user$sqrt$s__44945(good_enough_QMARK_, improve);
        good_enough_QMARK_ = new user$sqrt$good_enough_QMARK___44947(x);
        Object var10002 = x;
        x = null;
        improve = new user$sqrt$improve__44949(var10002);
        user$sqrt$s__44945 var10000 = (user$sqrt$s__44945)s;
        ((user$sqrt$s__44945)s).good_enough_QMARK_ = good_enough_QMARK_;
        var10000.improve = improve;
        user$sqrt$good_enough_QMARK___44947 var4 = (user$sqrt$good_enough_QMARK___44947)good_enough_QMARK_;
        user$sqrt$improve__44949 var5 = (user$sqrt$improve__44949)improve;
        return ((IFn)s).invoke(const__0);
    }

}

public final class user$sqrt$good_enough_QMARK___44947 extends AFunction {
    Object x;
    public static final Var const__1 = (Var)RT.var("user", "abs");
    public static final Var const__3 = (Var)RT.var("user", "square");

    public user$sqrt$good_enough_QMARK___44947(Object var1) {
        this.x = var1;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object guess) {
        DO var10000 = (DO)const__1.getRawRoot();
        DO var10001 = (DO)const__3.getRawRoot();
        Object var10002 = guess;
        guess = null;
        return Numbers.lt(var10000.invokePrim(RT.doubleCast((Number)Numbers.minus(var10001.invokePrim(RT.doubleCast((Number)var10002)), this.x))), 1.0E-4D)?Boolean.TRUE:Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}

public final class user$sqrt$improve__44949 extends AFunction {
    Object x;
    public static final Var const__0 = (Var)RT.var("user", "avg");

    public user$sqrt$improve__44949(Object var1) {
        this.x = var1;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object guess) {
        DDO var10000 = (DDO)const__0.getRawRoot();
        double var10001 = RT.doubleCast((Number)Numbers.divide(this.x, guess));
        Object var10002 = guess;
        guess = null;
        return var10000.invokePrim(var10001, RT.doubleCast((Number)var10002));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the wiseguy answer is that it would be most idiomatic not to define your own square root operation. `(Math/sqrt x)` which is an interop call against `java.util.Math.sqrt()` would be preferred. It's fairly common to see `(defn sqrt [x] (Math/sqrt x))` floating around, or at least that's something I've perpetrated for several projects.

An even better answer would be to use [clojure.algo.generic](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic) which already defines `sqrt` among other operations in an extensible and idiomatic fashion.

This particular implementation of Newton's Method is fine, and in a very traditional scheme style, but because it's using boxed arithmetic through multiple `fn`s it will be vastly outperformed by `Math/sqrt` and it provides none of the numeric tower flexibility of algo.generic, or an equivalent implementation atop algo.generic.

As to will the functions in the `letfn` be redefined every time, the traditional Scheme implementation of `letfn` is something like:

- Create a binding to `nil` for every `fn` name
- `setq` each binding to the `fn` body now that there is a binding for every name
- Evaluate the body form(s)

Clojure does the same thing under the hood. Each `fn` in the `letfn` is compiled to an `AFn` instance class, which accepts as instance arguments references to the closed over `fn`s. The emitted bytecode is logically the same format as the Scheme implementation:

- Bind the named local for each `fn` to a `Var`
- Initialize each `AFn` instance with the `Var`s corresponding to the other `letfn` bodies that it closes over
- Bind each instantiated `AFn` to the appropriate `Var`
- Evaluate the body form(s)

So technically yes, each binding in the `letfn` needs to be re-established each time the body is executed, and the new binding is of a new (anonymous) Var to a new `AFn` instance of the compiled classes. No lambda lifting or any other transformation occurs to prevent this, however the overhead from doing so is negligible.

Answer (score -1):

The following code shows the difference.  Note that a plain `let` is all you need to define local functions:

```
(defn my-inc [x] (+ 1 x))
(defn my-square [x] (* x x))
(println :1 (my-square (my-inc 2)))

(let [my-inc-2    (fn [x] (+ 1 x))
      my-square-2 (fn [x] (* x x)) ]
  (println :2 (my-square-2 (my-inc-2 2))))

(println :sqrt-9 (Math/sqrt 9))

;=> :1 9
;=> :2 9
;=> :sqrt-9 3.0
```

The only difference between the 2 cases is that visibility of `my-inc-2` and `my-square-2` is restricted to the `let` block.  I like this way better than using `letfn`, as I think the regular `(fn ...)` syntax is clearer.

With regards to `sqrt`, using the Java built-in function is much better than writing your own.

For numerical techniques in general, one effective technique is to use a polynomial first approximation, followed up by a few iterations of Newton's method. This is how Matlab computes the normal distribution function `N(0,1)`, for example.